# Jquery Horizontal Scroll on Click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get this horizontal section of the page to auto scroll when the left or right arrows are clicked.  I can get the Jquery code to run correctly in the console.  However, the auto scroll events won't run at all on my page.  Could anyone provide any insight into this issue?

The code is as follows :

HTML

```
<div class = "horizon horizon-prev">
      <img src = "../images/left-arrow.png" />
    </div>
    <div class = "horizon horizon-next">
      <img src = "../images/right-arrow.png" />
    </div>

  <div class="center" id="content">
      <div class=internal>
        div 1
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 2
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 3
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 4
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 5
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 6
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 7
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 8
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div.center {
 width: 90%;
 height: 210px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
  }
  div.internal {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
  }
```

Jquery

```
$('.horizon-prev').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=775px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('.horizon-next').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
   scrollLeft: "+=775px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Where are `.horizon-prev` and `.horizon-next` class?

Comment: @Error404 I've just edited the example to show where they are.  Sorry for the lack of code.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wokofepuvi/1/edit?html,css,js,output It works for me

Comment: As @VladGincher points this works ... Also I suggest you since you have `%` width to take the Scroll value from the actual width of `center` ... Check this https://jsfiddle.net/fwnv28hu/

Comment: @VladGincher check out sethspivey.com.  For some reason, it's only working when I run the code in the console.

Comment: Where you have that jquery code? I don´t see it in your page....

Comment: @DaniP It's in an external JS file

Comment: I see it now ... try `delegate` the event https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 5):

(based on looking at your site sethspivey.com)

You need to add the missing event parameter you are using, and also move the click handlers into document.ready, like so:

```
$(function() {
  $('.horizon-prev').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').animate({
      scrollLeft: "-=775px"
    }, "slow");
  });

   $('.horizon-next').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').animate({
     scrollLeft: "+=775px"
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I take your code as this, and it work perfectly.

```js
$('.horizon-prev').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=775px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('.horizon-next').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
   scrollLeft: "+=775px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
div.center {
 width: 90%;
 height: 210px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
  }
  div.internal {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center" id="content">
      <div class=internal>
        div 1
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 2
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 3
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 4
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 5
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 6
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 7
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 8
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <button class="horizon-prev">Prev</button>    <button class="horizon-next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that jQuery binded an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event on a div that isn't loaded yet. You should execute it only when the DOM is fully loaded.

To fix it, in the http://sethspivey.com/js/index.js file, change the code to:

```
/* CLICK SCROLL FUNCTIONS JQUERY */
$(function(){
  $('.horizon-prev').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').animate({
      scrollLeft: "-="+toScroll+"px"
    }, "slow");
  });

  $('.horizon-next').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').animate({
      scrollLeft: "+="+toScroll+"px"
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm after combining this and defining the scrollTo that DaniP provided in his jsfiddle.  Thank you

Comment: Re-edit your answer ... since you are using the code I provided on the comments please copy the complete code...Here is no `toScroll` value

Comment: @DaniP I used the code in http://sethspivey.com/js/index.js line 217, all I've done is adding `$(function(){` at the beginning and `});` at the end...

Answer (score 1):

this is an old post and maybe there is an easier way to achive this now, but nevertheless it helped me with a project I am working on now. This scrollLeft recommendation above works a treat, but when you get to the end of the div if you continue clicking right 5 times for example, it adds 5 x 200px to scrollLeft, so you have to click left 6 times to move back 200px. This additional code solved the issue for me. Alternatively you could disable the button when reaching the end/beginning of the content div:

```
$('.horizon-prev').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  let currentScroll = $('#content').get(0).scrollLeft;
  let scrollWidth = $('#content').get(0).scrollWidth;
  if((currentScroll - 200) <= 0){
        return;
  }else{
        $('#content').animate({
            scrollLeft: '-=200px'
        }, "slow");
  }
});


$('.horizon-next').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  let currentScroll = $('#content').get(0).scrollLeft;
  let scrollWidth = $('#content').get(0).scrollWidth;
  if((200 + currentScroll) >= scrollWidth){
        return;
  }else{
        $('#content').animate({
            scrollLeft: '+=200px'
        }, "slow");
  }
});
```

Comment: Works great, thanks, but I think you have two next selectors instead of next and prev

Comment: Indeed I did. Updated this now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With some modifications for better demonstration seems to me working fine:

```
<div class="horizon horizon-prev">
  <img src="../images/left-arrow.png" />
</div>
<div class="horizon horizon-next">
  <img src="../images/right-arrow.png" />
</div>

<div class="center" id="content">
  <div class=internal>
    div 1
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 2
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 3
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 4
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 5
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 6
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 7
  </div>
  <div class=internal>
    div 8
  </div>
```

```
div.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 210px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.internal {
  margin: -2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 198px;
  text-align: center;
}

$('.horizon-prev').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=198px"
  }, "slow");
});

$('.horizon-next').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=198px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w87xycrq/1